# gdb script to isolate a thread based on variable value

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, gdb

I have a program having over 300 threads to which I have attached gdb. I need to identify one particular thread whose call stack has a frame containing a variable whose value I want to use for matching. Can I script this in gdb?

```
(gdb) thread 3
[Switching to thread 3 (Thread 0x7f16c1eeb700 (LWP 18833))]
#4  0x00007f17f3a3bdd5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007f17f3a3fd12 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f17e72838be in __afr_shd_healer_wait (healer=healer@entry=0x7f17e05203d0) at afr-self-heald.c:101
#2  0x00007f17e728392d in afr_shd_healer_wait (healer=healer@entry=0x7f17e05203d0) at afr-self-heald.c:125
#3  0x00007f17e72848e8 in afr_shd_index_healer (data=0x7f17e05203d0) at afr-self-heald.c:572
#4  0x00007f17f3a3bdd5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f17f3302ead in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x00007f17e72848e8 in afr_shd_index_healer (data=0x7f17e05203d0) at afr-self-heald.c:572
572                     afr_shd_healer_wait (healer);
(gdb) p this->name
$6 = 0x7f17e031b910 "testvol-replicate-0"
```

For example, can I run a macro to loop over each thread, go to frame 3 in each of it, inspect the variable `this->name` and print the thead number only if the value matches `testvol-replicate-0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to integrate Python into GDB. Then, with the Python GDB API, you could loop over threads and search for a match. Below two examples of debugging threads with GDB and Python.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/11027
https://fy.blackhats.net.au/blog/html/2017/08/04/so_you_want_to_script_gdb_with_python.html